# Should MySQL's primary key be just INTEGER or should it be UNSIGNED INTEGER (of appropriate size)?

Tags: mysql, unsigned, signed

Let's say I'm creating a table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Should the primary key be simply `INT` or should I make it `UNSIGNED INT`? I know that a negative primary key doesn't make much sense, so I think it should be `UNSIGNED INT`. Although which one would be faster?

Comment: why not? if it's unique, it's ok

Comment: @Leo I'm just learning. If you say it's ok then I'll go ahead with UNSIGNED INT. :)

Comment: unsigned will give you a larger range. performance I don't know, but I guess it's quite the same for both options

Comment: The only problems with using unsigned tend to happen when you forget to use it (or are unable to) elsewhere -- and you might get truncation or some weird conversion to a floating point or who knows what. That's true with any choice, I suppose - if you stick it in the wrong variable, things blow up.

Comment: @bodacydo for `name` field much better will be to use `Varchar` than char.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid thinking about it altogether:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
    id SERIAL,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

(Which does create it as an unsigned int, and also adds the unique index and auto incrementing)

Comment: SERIAL is something new. TIL.

Comment: And just now I found `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 3):

We use `INT UNSIGNED` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` for all of our surrogate primary keys. We also use the name `id` for the column.

There's nothing problematic (or necessarily evil) with negative values for an integer PRIMARY KEY, a signed integer would be fine as well.

One issue to be aware of with an unsigned integer: the maximum value is LARGER than the maximum value of a signed integer. (INT UNSIGNED maximum value is 2^32-1, rather than 2^31-1.) Any client programs will need to be aware of this; mapping an INT UNSIGNED into a 32-bit signed integer (for example, a C int type) will be a problem if the value exceeds 2^31-1.

Comment: This tends to be especially problematic with php.

Answer (score 3):

If it's auto incremented, as they usually are, it should be unsigned, otherwise you will get unexpected sequencing at the overflow point.